# Swift code in playground vs. an actual class

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Odd thing happening here. The following code:

```
String(Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970*1000))
```

works in a playground but doesn't in a class. It crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

Any ideas why? Alternatively, how do I get a string of the above `NSTimeInterval`?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I need the result as Int, so 1402324472549 and not 1402324472549.64, for example.

Comment: In [David Berry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24124703/1548472)s answer below, he makes an interesting distinction of the playground being in 64bit-land vs classes are in 32bit-land.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a class definition:

```
var date = NSDate()
let myDateString = String(Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970()*1000))
println("Seconds = \(myDateString)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the root cause, but it is something to do with the type conversion. This works:

```
var date = NSDate()
var asString = "\(Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970*1000))"
println(asString)
```

Comment: It works, but it gives me 1402324472549.64, whereas I need 1402324472549. That was the whole point of converting to Int :-).

Comment: Crashes as well :-(. Does it work for you? (in a class, not playground).

Answer (score 2):

The crash is because you're overflowing a 32-bit signed int and swift by default does boundary checking on all operations.  Try:

```
"\(floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970)"
```

Comment: floor still gives me .0. Int64 worked though. What I found interesting is that in the playground it works, i.e. it gives the right result.

Comment: in the playground you're running in 64-bit land, which means that Int is 64-bits, so no overflow.